# Subscribe to all observables in a combineLatest

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, subscription, combinelatest

In my code I open a `matDialog` allowing XLSX extraction.

When opening this `matDialog`, data is loaded into the `ngOnInit()`, which may take some time.
That's why I use `combineLatest()` with `filter()` allowing me to wait for the result of the three queries to allow extraction.
I would now like to add a `mat-progress-bar determinate` to see where the extraction is going.
For that I would like to be able to modify my varibale `progress` with each result received.

So I used `map(result => {this.progress = this.progress + 30;}` on each request to increase the progress.
It works, but breaks my `combineLatest()`. The progression stops at 90% and I can not find a solution.

**Code:**

```
this.subscriptions$.add(combineLatest([
    this.storeWallets.loadInvoiceExtractionProduct(this.selectedWallet).pipe(
        //map(result => { this.progress = this.progress + 30; }),
        catchError(err => {
            console.error(err.message);
            return of(err);
        })
    ),
    this.storeWallets.loadInvoiceExtractionSupport(this.selectedWallet).pipe(
        //map(result => { this.progress = this.progress + 30; }),
        catchError(err => {
            console.error(err.message);
            return of(err);
        })
    ),
    this.storeWallets.loadInvoiceExtractionTraining(this.selectedWallet).pipe(
        //map(result => { this.progress = this.progress + 30; }),
        catchError(err => {
            console.error(err.message);
            return of(err);
        })
    ),
    ]).pipe(
        filter(results => results.every(res => !!res))
    ).subscribe(results => {
        //this.progress = 100;
        document.body.style.cursor = "default";
        this.waitExtraction = false;
    })
);
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
map(result => { this.progress = this.progress + 30; }),
```

will take every result and return *undefined*, as there's no return statement (therefore `filter` will filter out the results, and the subscriber won't be run). Replace `map` with `tap` operator and it should work.